# C++ error with operator overloading

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, syntax-error

I am trying to make program that uses operator overloading to do basic math operations on rational numbers. I keep getting an errors in the functions where it says i must have an arithmetic of enum type. Also I get an error istream where it says that the numerator and denominator are undefined.
Here is the header file:

```
#ifndef rational_H
#define rational_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Rational
{
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &  , const Rational &);
    friend istream & operator<<(istream & , const Rational &);
    public:
    // default constructor
    Rational(int = 0, int = 1);
    // overload operators for "normal" operation
    Rational operator+(const Rational&);
    Rational operator-(const Rational&);
    Rational operator*(const Rational&);
    Rational operator/(const Rational&);

    operator double();
    // overload relational operators for "normal" operation
    bool operator>(const Rational&) const;
    bool operator<(const Rational&) const;
    bool operator>=(const Rational&) const;
    bool operator<=(const Rational&) const;
    bool operator==(const Rational&) const;
    bool operator!=(const Rational&) const;

protected:
    int *numerator;
    int *denominator;
    void reduction(void);
};

#endif
```

// this part of code is from my rational cpp file//

```
// default constructor//
Rational::Rational( int n, int d )
{
   *numerator =1 ;
   // sets numerator
   if(d == 0)
       d = 1; // If denominator is zero then set to one.
   *denominator = 0;

   // sets denominator
   reduction(); // store the fraction in reduced form
} 

// all the other operators have the same error as well//
Rational Rational::operator-(const Rational&a)
{
    Rational sub;

    sub.numerator = *this->numerator * a.denominator -//the error is with the 'a'needs to be an arithmetic type or enum type//
    *this->denominator * a.numerator;
    sub.denominator = *denominator * a.denominator;
    sub.reduction();
    return sub;
}

    //also the istream part has an error where the denominator and numerator is underfined as well//

istream& operator >> ( istream& inputStream, Rational& rnum )
{
    inputStream>>rnum.*numerator;//numerator and denmoinator undefined for some reason//
    inputStream.ignore(1);
    inputStream>>rnum.*denominator;

    return inputStream; 
}
```

Comment: Get rid of those pointers. Your use of them is very wrong in three different ways.

Comment: My first question is, why are your structure members *pointers*? That makes no sense.

Comment: This actually has nothing to do with operator overloading.

Comment: By the way, operators with compound assignment counterparts are usually implemented in terms of those. For example, `operator-` would be a simple single call to `operator-=`.

Comment: You have a reference variable Rational &rnum. And if you are trying to access its class variables then you have to use the same C++ calling convention, that`s rnum.numerator and rnum.denominator. Since you have a reference to these variables and not a pointer. Even though your numerator and denominator are pointers, you cannot dereference them neither can you overload its calling conventions.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiples small errors in your code.
First of all you should not be using pointers for these members, it does not bring any advantages.

But as you chose this way, you have to dereference them each time you want to read or update them, which hasn't be done in your `operator-` implementation, and incorrectly in your `operator>>` implementation (the asterisk needs to be put before the whole expression).

Next error in the code you provided, you marked as friend `operator<<(istream & , const Rational &)` in your class definition, but it should have been `operator>>`. And this declaration needs to match the definition that appears next (i.e., remove the `const` of the second argument, which obviously has to be mutated).

And, last but not least, the undefined behavior caused by all the dereferencing of you uninitialized pointers…

Comment: i tried making the corrections but i keep getting errors could you show me an example of how the operator should be overloaded

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a copy and past error. The line

```
friend istream & operator<<(istream & , const Rational &);
```

should be

```
friend istream & operator>>(istream & , Rational &);
```

Your implementation later on in the file has:

```
istream& operator >> ( istream& inputStream, Rational& rnum )
{
 ...
}
```

It matches the second declaration, not the first one.